# Multi Language with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apc, multilingual

I am building multi language for ecommerce site.
The whole site is storing data in flat files at the moment so dynamic data such as product details will just include different language flat files but there are some static data such as page title, menu, etc. and I want to store "static" language data in mysql database and retrieve back with apc cache to show language elements in page but i am not too sure that it is the best ideas. We will hire agency to translate text for us and i need to build CMS for editing languages.

Any suggestion will be welcome. 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Make sure to use UTF-8 in your database, declare it in the HTML files, and make sure your editor is saving in UTF-8 without BOM. Notepad++ saves in ANSI by default.

Comment: Thank you and it is helpful and is it good ideas to use database and apc cache? I m just worry for performance of site. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if you want the easy way out then you can have Google take care of the translations for you. https://translate.google.com/manager/website/settings

Comment: thx you for urs advice :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use joomla & virtuemart for multilingual e-commerce site. it is easy to integrate & manageable from admin panel.

Comment: Thank you for yours kindness suggestion. I know there is joomla, other good CMS but we don't want to use it. We just want change multi language to our site.